# Should Rails redirect_to be sending html?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirecttoaction

In most frameworks, sending a redirect means setting the HTTP headers and exiting without sending any HTML data back to the browser. However, using Firebug I see that Rails is not following this convention:

```
def update
    @phone_number = PhoneNumber.find(params[:id])
    if @phone_number.update_attributes(params[:phone_number])
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated phone number."
      redirect_to @phone_number
    else
      render :action => 'edit'
    end
end
```

In response, the headers have:

```
Connection  close
Date        Tue, 27 Oct 2009 06:17:00 GMT
X-Runtime    28
Location      http://localhost:3000/phone_numbers/1999521184
```

**and**  it also has the results from the show action, *twice*

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting.  It appears that firebug is lying to me.   Using WireShark, I confirmed that it is in fact not sending the page data, just the redirect and a basic "You are being redirected" message. Looks like a bug with firebug.

Answer (score 1):

Could be a bug with Firebug.  Another thing to try this:

```
redirect_to @phone_number and return
```